# How Sorting Data With Underscore In Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to sorting data when contained in the underscore ?

Explanation is on the picture,,

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: can the numbers be anny number? So `ABC_1_1` can also be `ABC_100_1000` ?  And is the max of number of numbers always 2?

Comment: Please, put your example in your question, don't use external image

Comment: Hint: Research on this website how can split strings with nested SUBSTRING_INDEX functions and use CAST to convert it into a int.. Then you can simply use ORDER BY on those numbers .. Atleast if you are looking for a MySQL only method.

Comment: Technically it **is** sorting correctly - you're sorting on strings so `10` comes before `2`. You'd be better off altering your database table to add a `priority` column that's an integer type and sorting on that.

Comment: *"You'd be better off altering your database table to add a priority column that's an integer type and sorting on that. "* @CD001 most likely but we don't know the topicstarters usercase.. topicstarter keep in mind adding a "sorting" column only really works when you only need to deal with one "group" which you need to sort...

Comment: @RaymondNijland digit numbers are unlimited, and can change

Answer (score 2):

You want a natural sort.

```
<?php

$items =
[
'ABC_1_1',
'ABC_1_3',
'ABC_1_10',
'ABC_1_11',
'ABC_1_5',
'ABC_1_7'
];

sort($items, SORT_NATURAL);
var_dump($items);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "ABC_1_1"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "ABC_1_3"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "ABC_1_5"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "ABC_1_7"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "ABC_1_10"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "ABC_1_11"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select id_code
from tablename
order by 
substring_index(substring_index(id_code,'_',-2),'_',1),substring_index(id_code,'_',-1)
```

Comment: Not working,,

Any a simple query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in MYSQL to split your string, and order by parts :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID_DATA, '_', 1) as part1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID_DATA, '_', 2), '_', -1) as part2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID_DATA, '_', -1) as part3,
FROM table
ORDER BY part1, part2, part3
```

Comment: you are using the nesting wrong... see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8rr4TNiZrM8Uuhrhzq2rb1/0)

Comment: ah yes you're right